# Access Violation on an attribut of dataset Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, dataset, access-violation

After a lot of research, i decided to post my question here.

After the excusion of a big quantity of code, i get at the beautiful message "Access Violation ....". with the debug mode, i saw that  this line **"dsPRINCIPAL.DataSet.FieldByName('ID_NATURE').AsInteger"**  and all attributs of my dataset show this 
**"Violation d'accès pour 4034D1E0 accédant à FFFFFFFF".**

My dsPRINCIPAL and the Dataset are active and in Edit Mode, and have 1 record(not empty).

Can you plz help me undestand why i have access violation on this line.

Here is the code:

`if dsCTC_PRINCIPAL.DataSet.FieldByName('ID_NATURE_CTC').AsInteger:=Variable.Get(VCA‌​_PREFERENCES +'.ID_NATURE_CTC_MGE_SUIVI',scGlobal).asInteger; dsCTC_PRINCIPAL.DataSet.FieldByName('ID_OBJET_CTC').AsInteger:=Variable.Get(VCA_‌​PREFERENCES +'.ID_OBJET_HL_MGE',scGlobal).asInteger; dsCTC_PRINCIPAL.DataSet.FieldByName('QTEPASSE').AsInteger:=0;`

Regards.

Comment: place a break point on or before that line, and add a watch on or hover over `dsPRINCIPAL.DataSet` to ensure it isn't nil.

Comment: FFFFFFFF is an integer of value -1 : it looks like this was assigned as a pointer to some object?  Could you show the code surrounding this call?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect `dsPRINCIPAL.DataSet` or even `dsPRINCIPAL.DataSet.FieldByName('ID_NATURE')` returns `nil`, so calling `AsInteger` virtual method raised the access violation.

Try this:

```
var NatureField: TField;

if dsPRINCIPAL.DataSet=nil then
  raise Exception.Create('dsPRINCIPAL.DataSet not assigned');
NatureField := dsPRINCIPAL.DataSet.FieldByName('ID_NATURE');
if NatureField=nil then
  raise Exception.Create('ID_NATURE field missing');
...
NatureValue := NatureField.AsInteger;
```

By the way, for performance reasons, since `FieldByName()` can be slow, when you retrieve some data in a loop, it is a good habit to use a `NatureField: TField` local assessor.

Comment: Hello, Thanks to all for your answers.

Comment: Hello, Thanks to all for your answers. I tried what you said Arnaud. but it generate no Exception. here is the code ` if 
       dsCTC_PRINCIPAL.DataSet.FieldByName('ID_NATURE_CTC').AsInteger:=Variable.Get(VCA_PREFERENCES +'.ID_NATURE_CTC_MGE_SUIVI',scGlobal).asInteger;
       dsCTC_PRINCIPAL.DataSet.FieldByName('ID_OBJET_CTC').AsInteger:=Variable.Get(VCA_PREFERENCES +'.ID_OBJET_HL_MGE',scGlobal).asInteger;
       dsCTC_PRINCIPAL.DataSet.FieldByName('QTEPASSE').AsInteger:=0; ` here is the code , it bugs at the seconde line, i remover the code proposed by Arnault due to text lenght restriction

Comment: @Fozix - if you have code to add you should edit your question and place it there - there is no limitation that way and it is easier for everyone to see.

Comment: @Fozix your new code contains nothing of the advice in Arnaud's answer.  Please post the *full* code in your question.